# Как правильно собрать types declaration file при публикации модуля TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Есть модуль, написанный на TypeScript. Для своего удобства я создал файл `types/index.d.ts`, в котором прописал основные `type` и `interface`, чтобы в дальнейшем импортировать их через `import { MyInterface } from '../types'`. Того же требует и eslint (см. [typescript-eslint/triple-slash-reference](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/triple-slash-reference.md)). Делаю сборку проекта и на выходе получаю index.js и index.d.ts, однако компилятор TypeScript не подхватывает мой файл с декларацией, а просто копирует `import` так словно я просто импортирую какой-то модуль. Соответственно на выходе я получаю абсолютно нерабочий файл декларации. Указание `"typeRoots": ["./types"]` в tsconfig.json не решило проблему. Как всё это исправить? Хочу, чтобы на выходе у меня был единый декларативный файл, содержащий как мои собственные типы и интерфейсы, так и сгенерированные компилятором при сборке.

Comment: 1) сама либа написана на JS или TS 2) публикации Где? 3) "Делаю сборку" чем? 4) "словно я просто импортирую какой-то модуль" да, именно так типы и должны подхватываться, без каких-либо отдельных телодвижений !!! 5) либа в броузер или ноду? 6) если в браузер - как подключается

Comment: а ещё - создай минимальный(тестовый) проект на гитхабе и дай на него ссылку

Comment: ДА ! мы ведь говорим про NPM модули ?